# Installing Mcrypt extension for PHP on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: php, macos, installation, mcrypt

How do I install mcrypt? I'm using Leopard 10.5.8 with PHP5.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I just spent 1.5 hours trying to do this myself on 10.6.7

I believe the solution was this:

I installed `php5-mcrypt + universal` with macports:

```
$ sudo macports php5-mcrypt +universal
```

then, you can't just put `extension=mycrypt.so` in the `php.ini` file, you have to put the direct path i.e.:

```
extension = /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/mcrypt.so
```

you see, PHP looks in `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/`
which is the difference I missed!!

Then just restart apache with your

```
$ sudo apachectl -k graceful
```

and then

```
$ php -m | grep mcrypt
```

to make sure it's there.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 5):

```
 # Edit macports.conf
cd /opt/local/etc/macports
sudo nano macports.conf
# Change the line ....
universal_archs ppc i386
# to ...
universal_archs ppc ppc64 i386 x86_64

# Get the MCRYPT Library
sudo port install mcrypt +universal
```

Source: [This page](http://www.malisphoto.com/tips/php-on-os-x.html#Anchor-InstallLib).

Comment: Follow the instructions; checking info.php -- no mcrypt. Ideas?

Comment: Did php compile without warnings with mcrypt enabled?

Comment: In which stage? I'm not quite sure. If you'd tell me which command to run, it'll be very helpful.

Comment: Well if you look at the linked page, below "Build and Install PHP". Commands to run are the lines in the orange box, not starting with hashmarks.

Comment: Error: Target org.macports.extract returned: shell command failed (see log for details)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you've installed PHP.

If you installed PHP via macports, you can:

```
sudo port install php5-mcrypt +universal
```

If you custom-compiled your PHP, it's probably easiest to just recompile with:

```
--with-mcrypt=/path/to/mcrypt
```

(Not sure where macports actually keeps it, since I don't use macports, but just compile my AMP stack (and most dependencies) from source)

Comment: I tried running 'sudo port install php5-mcrypt +universal" and got this: 

<code>Skipping org.macports.activate (mcrypt +universal) since this  port is already active</code>

But info.php shows nothing, and phpMyAdmin still claims mcrypt is nowhere around its sight.