# Mcrypt installed but doesn't show up on PHPINFO

Tags: php, apache, mcrypt

I think I managed to install mcrypt lib. The files are in place, but it looks like the library doesn't run at all.

Tried to add:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

to PHP.INI; no good. Any help?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448897/adding-mcrypt-to-php

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I did get far ahead from that question, and was unable to remove it due to posted answers.

Comment: yup... here are also d answers...
http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=337857.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting Apache? It won't recognise the new installed module until you do so AFAIK.  Also, you've written you "think" you've installed it - did you use eg apt-get or yum to install it (eg `apt-get install php-mcrypt`) or just download it?

Comment: apt-get results with "command not found". I manually downloaded the library, ran ./configure, then make and then sudo make install.

Did I do wrong?

Comment: Tried to install it with MacPorts: "sudo port install libmcrypt". Result: "Error: Target org.macports.activate returned: Image error: Another version of this port (libmcrypt @2.5.8_1+universal) is already active. Error: Status 1 encountered during processing."

So Why oh why it doesn't load with Apache?

Answer (score 3):

Anyone actually looking for an answer to this on Ubuntu OS greater than 13, you have to run

```
php5enmod mcrypt
```

and then  restart apache. This is new and follows the same route you would use to enable apache modules as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same problem.

Sometimes it doesn't work when you add in /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini

add it in /etc/php.ini , the main php config file

Restart apache

You are done.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check if you actually edited **apache2**/php.ini not **cli**/php.ini.

The full path is /etc/php/7.4/**apache2**/php.ini if you use Ubuntu 20.04.