# Where and how to set DYLD environment in Mac OS X

Tags: php, apache, mcrypt

I'm in the middle a long quest, by now, trying to install mcrypt library to Mac OS X PHP (Previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448897/adding-mcrypt-to-php), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450686/mcrypt-installed-but-doesnt-show-up-on-phpinfo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451047/ldconfig-for-mac-os-x)).

I narrowed it down to a possible solution the includes setting a parameter in the DYLD environment (or something; I'm guessing here). Anyone has any idea where this environment is declared?

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man dyld

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Weird. Tried it, and resulted with: "No manual entry for DYLD".

Comment: Can you direct to me as to HOW to set these variables?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/dyld

Example:

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/opt/lib/